# Failed to download zendframework/zendxml from dist:

Tags: git, zend-framework

Failed to download zendframework/zendxml from dist: You must enable the openssl
extension to download files via https
Now trying to download from source
- Installing zendframework/zendxml (1.0.0)
Cloning 559b34f426d33a11c3db118e00ce14bb8dc64e5f

[RuntimeException]
Failed to clone git@github.com:zendframework/ZendXml.git, git was not found
, check that it is installed and in your PATH env.

'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I can't able to install zend in my system please some body help me for this,
every time when i start exploring zend same error is repeated again
please help me for this

Answer (score 1):

Composer is trying to install the `zendframework/zendxml` package. In order to do that, you either need the openssl PHP extension installed/enabled (so PHP can download from https URLs), or git installed (so Composer can download from source).

Fix either of these issues (I'd suggest openssl) and you should be good to go.